# Sahih Buckari Book of Funerals number 435 hadith explanation

Tags: hadith-interpretation

> Narrated Jabir: A man was buried along with my father and I did not
>   like it till I took him (i.e. my father) out and buried him in a
>   separate grave.

**Sahih Buckari Book of Funerals number 435**

Who's father this hadith talking about . Is it Allahs apostals or Narrator Jabir's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Arabic, there is no indication that Jabir is quoting anyone; the "my father" in this case is apparently referring to Jabir's father (i.e. the Ansar Abdullah ibn Amr ibn Haram) who died during the battle of Uhud.

There are other hadiths on the subject which provide more detail.  One example (which is also [narrated through Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1351)) is as follows:

> Narrated Jabir: When the time of the Battle of Uhud approached, my
> father called me at night and said, "I think that I will be the first
> amongst the companions of the Prophet to be martyred. I do not
> leave anyone after me dearer to me than you, except Allah's Messenger's
> soul and I owe some debt and you should repay it and treat your
> sisters favorably (nicely and politely)." So in the morning **he was the
> first to be martyred and was buried along with another (martyr). I did
> not like to leave him with the other (martyr) so I took him out of the
> grave** after six months of his burial and he was in the same condition
> as he was on the day of burial, except a slight change near his ear.

Again, the Arabic doesn't indicate that he is quoting anybody, so there's no reason to believe that this is referring to anybody but Jabir's own father, and especially not the father of the prophet who by the time of Uhud had been dead for over fifty years.